# how object array can be write or read in a text file in c#?

Tags: c#

I have data stored  array of object of class  which I am trying to write in text file ... (this is not complete code)

```
class Program
{
    public int i;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();

        user[] obj = new user[10];
        for ( p.i = 0; p.i < 10; p.i++)
        obj[p.i] = new user();
        int index = 0;
```

Comment: So what is your question?  If you don't clarify what you're looking for *specifically*, this question will be closed as unclear.

Comment: What is the definition of `user`? Please post **all** of the relevant code, not some uncompilable snippet.

Comment: what is the question

Answer (score 2):

Make Your Class look something like this:

```
[Serializable()]    //Set this attribute to all the classes that want to serialize
public class User : ISerializable //derive your class from ISerializable
{
    public int userInt;
    public string userName;

    //Default constructor
    public User()
    {
        userInt = 0;
        userName = "";
    }

   //Deserialization constructor.
   public User(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
   {
      //Get the values from info and assign them to the appropriate properties
      userInt = (int)info.GetValue("UserInt", typeof(int));
      userName = (String)info.GetValue("UserName", typeof(string));
   }

   //Serialization function.
   public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
   {
      //You can use any custom name for your name-value pair. But make sure you
      // read the values with the same name. For ex:- If you write userInt as "UserInt"
      // then you should read the same with "UserInt"
      info.AddValue("UserInt", userInt);
      info.AddValue("UserName", userName);
  }
}
```

Now to read and write you can do these:

```
User user=new User();

using(StreamWriter sw=new StreamWriter(/*Filename goes here*/))
{
  using(BinaryFormatter bformatter=new BinaryFormatter())
  {
    bformatter.Serialize(sw, user);
  }
}

using(StreamReader sr=new StreamReader(/*Filename goes here*/))
{
  using(BinaryFormatter bformatter=new BinaryFormatter())
  {
    user=(User)bformatter.Deserialize(sr);
  }
}
```

I got lots of this code from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1789/Object-Serialization-using-C

Comment: Sorry, this is just plain incorrect. `p` is the `Program` instance, and you aren't sure that `user` is even convertible to/from a string if that's what you meant.

Comment: that's why I said add a toString function

Comment: No, I have to agree with Ron, this is a poor answer.

Comment: Still wrong, unless you can convert back from the string to the object (which is not usually the case), you can't read it back out of the file and reconstruct the user from it.

Comment: @RonBeyer it doesn't say he wants to read from the text file

Comment: @SethKitchen, yes, it does. Read the title: *"how object array can be write or **read** in a text file in c#?"*

Comment: @RonBeyer oh, I never go off titles. My bad. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: I would improve it such that you can have a complete example (including serializing the user to/from a string) and read/write, or yes, delete otherwise you will probably keep getting downvotes.

Comment: Thats one way of going about it and I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @SethKitchen -- I've also removed my downvote.  Good job improving your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Read or Write Text-Files I would suggest to look at the 
System.IO Streamreader/Streamwriter Class

Take a look:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx